# Chroot won't work with OpenSSH

Tags: ssh, sftp

I have the latest OpenSSH, I have a group "members" with 5 users. I need to get SFTP to  certain directory, nothing else. I seem to be able to do it with Chroot, but it's not working. Heres my /etc/ssh/sshd_config:
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

```
Match Group members
        ChrootDirectory %h
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
        AllowTcpForwarding no
```

My error is this:

```
connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

I'm lost.

Comment: What version of OpenSSH are you using? "Latest" won't mean much after a couple of months. Also, what about the logs from the server?

Comment: Though it is almost certainly not related to your `connection refused` message, you should read closely about the permissions required for the `ChrootDirectory` setting.  The permissions requirements are very strict.

Answer (score 1):

The `connection refused` message usually means that there is nothing listening on the relevant `interface:port`.

The default for sshd is to listen on port 22 on all interfaces so the error message suggests that your sshd isn't configured to listen on 127.0.0.1:22.

Check /etc/ssh/sshd_config to ensure that sshd is listening on port 22, if it's not then there will be a `Port` directive. Use `-p` with your utilities to connect to the non-standard port.

Check to see if sshd has been restricted to particular interfaces - there will be `ListenAddress` directives - if configured try connecting on the relevant IP address.